# How do I fix "ImportError: cannot import name 'mknod' from 'os'" issue?

Tags: python, github, operating-system, importerror, mknod

I am trying to make something from Github run but I keep getting:
ImportError: cannot import name 'mknod' from 'os'

When I run "python program.py" this issue comes up and I have no idea how to fix it. I am on Windows 10

I have tried searching forums for answers but I cannot find any solution